# List of embassies closed in Damascus (Syria)

Tags: syria, embassy

Is there a list of Embassies closed in Syria between 2008 and 2018?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you [google](https://www.google.com/search?source=hp&ei=hrSpWsu_Msm7ggfv0LfwAQ&q=embassies+in+syria&oq=embassies+in+syria&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0j0i22i30k1l6.605.3626.0.3888.19.15.0.3.3.0.95.1045.15.15.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..1.18.1060.0..0i131k1j0i131i46k1j46i131k1j0i10k1.0.qgVbm_1zOsI) or [bing](https://www.bing.com/search?q=embassies+in+syria&qs=n&form=QBLH&sp=-1&pq=embassies+in+syria&sc=1-18&sk=&cvid=828A4E3683C1401686F1A9AB2579D401) "embassies in Syria", the first listing is:

> **[List of diplomatic missions in Syria - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_in_Syria)**

On that page you will find the list of embassies in Damascus along with status information, including embassies that are closed and the year they closed.

Comment: Thank you. Fascinating most NATO embassies + KSA closed in 2012 around the time of "Arab Spring". No mention of Israel Embassy but Syria hosts Palestinian Refugees so they might never have had an Embassy there. Thanks again for fascinating reading.

Comment: Israel has embassies in only a few Arab countries. I agree, I don't think they've ever had an embassy in Syria. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_diplomatic_missions_of_Israel

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix : Since that last comment of yours is both off-topic and with a strong potential to arouse polemics, I suggest deleting it before it ignites a political debate or a trolling feast...

Comment: @Evargalo Done and Thanks for the Trolling Feast heads up.